# iOS Audio - varispeed with precision

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avplayer, audioqueue

I am looking to modify the playback rate of a sound with precision, with the possibility to use a master clock to synchronize 2 audio players.

I have seen that AVPlayer and AVAudioPlayer are able to use a master clock as well as modify rate, but rates are too limited ( ~0.5 -> 2.0 ) with a low precision; I would like to be able to set rates like ( 0.999996 ).

I'm afraid Audio Queues won't support a master clock - removing the synchronization.

I have found in [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationAudioSettings_Constants/Reference/reference.html) : AVAudioTimePitchAlgorithmSpectral, which looks very interesting, but I haven't been able to find any examples, neither any explanation on how to use it...

Also, in iOS 7 slideshows, I have found those pitch algorithm :

[image: Time pitch algorithm]

But no sample code or which interfaces to use against those algorithms.

Also, does OpenAL could do the job ?

Many thanks